# inout port with real datatype in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I need to have an `inout` port with `real` dataytype in my module. Also I need to have multiple driver resolution capability in that port. (Saw about `nettype`, but didn't see usage of that in module ports in LRM)

Here is a sample code.

```
module abc (
  input real vref1, 
  output real vout);

  assign vout = vref1 * 3.17;
endmodule

module def (
  input logic out_en, 
  input logic data, 
  output logic vref1);

  bufif1 b1 (vref1, data, out_en);
endmodule

module top (
  inout real vref1,
  input logic out_en,
  input logic data,
  output real vout);
  
  logic vref1_dig_l;

  assign vref1 = (vref1_dig_l === 1'bz) ? 100.0 : ((vref1_dig_l == 1'b0) ? 0.0 : 20.0);

  abc a1 (vref1, vout);
  def d1 (out_en, data, vref1_dig_l);
endmodule

module temp ();
  real  vref1;
  logic out_en;
  logic data;
  real vout;

  top t1 (vref1, out_en, data, vout);

  initial 
    $monitor("vref1 - %0f, out_en - %0b, data - %0b, vout - %0f", vref1, out_en, data, vout);

  initial begin
    #1 vref1 = 5.0; out_en = $random()%2; data = $random();
    #1 vref1 = 5.0; out_en = $random()%2; data = $random();
    #1 vref1 = 5.0; out_en = $random()%2; data = $random();
    #1 vref1 = 5.0; out_en = $random()%2; data = $random();
    #1 vref1 = 5.0; out_en = $random()%2; data = $random();
    #1 vref1 = 5.0; out_en = $random()%2; data = $random();
    #1 vref1 = 5.0; out_en = $random()%2; data = $random();
    #1 vref1 = 5.0; out_en = $random()%2; data = $random();
  end
endmodule
```

This is giving me the following error -

```
  inout real vref1,
                 |
xmvlog: *E,SVNTRL (../b.sv,25|17): A module port that is a net cannot be of type 'real' or 'shortreal' by SystemVerilog language rules.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following:

```
nettype real nreal;

module top (
  inout nreal vref1,
  ...
```

however, `real` is not a synthesizable concept and cannot be used in the gate-level logic, so the following is illegal: `bufif1 b1 (vref1, data, out_en)` with verif1 as real.

Another way to work around your issues is using of system verilog functions for conversion real to bits and vice versa (lrm 20.5)

```
    [63:0] $realtobits ( real_val )
    real $bitstoreal ( bit_val )
```

for assignment issues in the init block of the temp module:

by verilog rules lhs of any assignment from a procedural block must be a variable. 'initial' block is a procedural block. 'net' is not a variable.

In temp you have to declare vref1 as 'nreal', which is a net type and you cannot assign it from a procedural block. You would need a varialbe as an intermediate stage:

```
nreal vref1;
real vref1_real;
assign nreal = vref1_real;

...
initial begin
    vref1_real = your expression;
...
```

The above  would fix your assignment issues.

It also looks like in your case a resolution function is needed. Something like the following can help:

```
function automatic real nres_avg (input real drivers[]);
    return drivers.sum/drivers.size(); // average of all drivers
endfunction
nettype real nreal with nres_avg;
```

Comment: This is not synthesizable code. I can probably add resolution function for `nreal` type. Right?

Comment: No, as soon as you use `real`, the code is not synthesizable. You can use real in TB and convert it to bits when handling it to RTL; then convert it back to real in TB.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I am using this in TB only, not RTL. But for this as `inout` net. I also need to write resolution function. Right?

Comment: it is up to you. you can write one or rely on the default. At least according to the standard. I do not have experience there.

Comment: I am getting assignment errors for this `nettype`. Can you show a working example with assignments?

Comment: what kind of error? your assignment in the `top` module works for me.

Comment: Sorry for updating the code, but I have updated the question, where `top` module is instantiated in `temp` module, which is final. I am getting assignment error in `vref1` assignment in `temp` module

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in net object like `wire`, `tri`, `wand`, etc. cannot have a data type other than those made up from the 4-state type `logic`. The built-in nets all have pre-defined resolution functions for when there are multiple drivers.

An `inout` is expected to have multiple drivers, so only nets are allowed on that kind of port.
If you want a `real` datatype on a net, it needs to be defined with user defined `nettype` so a resolution function can be associated with the net. i.e. do you want the individual drivers to be averaged, summed, max value, etc. There are some examples in the 1800-2017, and most tools provide these as readily available packages.

Comment: Can user defined `nettype` be used as a port? I couldnt see any example of that in LRM.

Comment: Yes. Section *23.3.3 Port connection rules* defines this, but there are no examples in the LRM. However, there is an example of a generic `interconnect` that passes a real nettype through a port.

Comment: If possible, can u share the example or let me know where it is in LRM?

Comment: Section *6.6.8 Generic interconnect*.